# Javascript/HTML5 using image to fill canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to get an image to fill up my canvas. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
var blueprint_background = new Image();
blueprint_background.src = 'images/blueprint_background.png'; 
var pattern = context.createPattern(blueprint_background, "repeat");

context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fill();
```

The issue is that nothing shows up. I was able to do the the basic context.fillRect(..) example, but this is giving me troubles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to wait until the image loads, use the image's onload property to know when it loads.

```
var blueprint_background = new Image();
blueprint_background.src = 'images/blueprint_background.png'; 
blueprint_background.onload = function(){
    var pattern = context.createPattern(this, "repeat");
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
    context.fill();
};
```

Comment: I'm seeing mismatched parenthesis? I'm not too familiar with javascript. EDIT - tried removing the ')' to fix the syntax error but the image still didn't load

Comment: Oi, I fixed it by adding (just before context.fill()): context.rect(x,y,width,height); Then it did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

## Be aware if someone wants to create pattern from image within Worker.

Inside Worker class Image is not defined!

```
ReferenceError: Image is not defined
```

In such case we can do the following:

```
const result = await fetch('./image.png');
const blob = await result.blob();
const image = await createImageBitmap(blob);
const pattern = canvasContext2D.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
```

And then simply fill OffscreenCanvasContext2D:

```
canvasContext2D.fillStyle = pattern;
canvasContext2D.fill();
```

References:

- OffscreenCanvas - [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas)
- OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D - [html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#offscreencanvasrenderingcontext2d)
- Worker - [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker)
- Fetch - [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- Blob - [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
- createImageBitmap - [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap)
- createPattern - [html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-createpattern)